# Correct way of embedding an iframe with a remote website in a metro app

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am facing problems when embedding external websites via iframe in my win 8 metro app.

I just do it the usual way like

```
<iframe src="http://d1303.de/boom.htm"></iframe>
```

If there is something seriously wrong on the embedded webpage (javascript errors..., like it is the case with http://d1303.de/boom.htm), my whole app crashes and Visual Studio complains about something in some script file deep in the included website.

Is there something special I have to take into account when dealing with remote iframes?

Comment: Have you tried the HTML Control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700625.aspx Have a look at the last example where you can set the URI. I guess this the XAML counterpart for webviewer.

Comment: The HTML Control doesn't seem to be able to handle remote URLs. `var htmlControl = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(document.getElementById("controlDiv"), { uri: 'http://www.d-mueller.de' });` crashes whereas the same code with a local html file works.

Comment: this site works in the browser fine? I just created an app with an iframe pointing to workflow (something I use every day), and it's in an iframe fine & dandy.

Comment: @DominicHopton: mywebsite.net is not the real website.

Comment: Try this one: `<iframe src="http://d1303.de/boom.htm"></iframe>`

Comment: your example will crash. it has non-functioning code. Theres no such thing as document.foo, so it explodes. if you want to handle those errors, put an onerror handler in your app, and silently eat them.

Comment: @DominicHopton: Of course will the example crash, that's why I created it. What's the Win 8 way of creating an onerror handler? `WinJS.Application.onerror = function() {};` does not catch this error.

Comment: Return true from it, I think (or it's false). Can't remember

Comment: I'm sorry, it just doesn't work this way. That error handler is not even invoked, so no matter what I return, the `console.log` before that is never being reached.

Comment: So, any idea? Still couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked this question over at the msdn forums and finally got a helping answer [from Steven Cheng here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/7114e66e-4fcd-47e9-8d3d-339adbe3110b):

> For Windows Store javascript based application, external web pages
>   referenced via iframe will be loaded in a different context than the
>   local pages (loaded from project content folders). Thus, the iframe
>   hosted external page will not be able to access some system APIs and
>   resources.
>
> For your case, I don't think the iframe hosted external page should
>   cause the main Windows Store app (the host application) to crash. I've
>   created a simple test Windows Store javascript app (use the Navigation
>   project template) and add a page to show the
>   "http://d1303.de/boom.htm" page in an iframe element. Here is the
>   behavior I've got:
>
> 1) When starting through "Ctrl + F5", when navigate to the iframe
>   page, the page just failed to load iframe content since there is
>   script error.But the hosting app doesn't crash and I can still
>   navigate back to other pages to work well on other pages.
>
> 2) When starting through "F5" to debug the application, it will break
>   into Visual Studio when navigating to the iframe page. This is because
>   the default debug setting will break into VS IDE when there is
>   unhandled js exception occured in application (you can see the
>   configuration through "Debug --> Exceptions..." menu). Also, If I
>   choose "continue", the app can still go ahead and function(navigate to
>   other pages to work).
>
> So the script error in the iframe referenced page will just break its
>   own page. For more information about the different context of web
>   pages loaded in javascript/html based windows store app, the following
>   book is quite good for you:
>
> Free ebook: Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
>   (First Preview)
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/06/04/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript-first-preview.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Hi since in windows 8 you cannot inject from other domains, you cannot just embed you iframe inside your code but what you can do is :

you can make a div than you set the innerHTML inside the div with the response static to other URL, you can try like this :

---HTML---

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

---JS---

```
WinJS.xhr({
url: 'http://yourwebsitehere'
}).done(function (result) {
     var domContainer = document.getElementById("container");
     domContainer.innerHTML = toStaticHTML(result.response);
});
```

But it will not act like an iframe overall, but you can still use it, if you just want to show a page from other domains.

-Yusak Setiawan-

http://apptivate.ms/apps/1271/mathboard

Comment: I want to be able to still browse the page as usual, e.g. write comments or login / logout. I think this won't be possible in that way.

Comment: This answer is incorrect -- iframes are supported, and do support this scenario.

Comment: Yes iframe is support in windows 8 but you cannot refer to the other domain Dominic Hopton, if you say support could you please tell me how to do it ?